# Java TCP Socket - Send command to controller

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, microcontroller

As you understand from the title i have [a controller](http://www.onbonbx.com/en/cp/html/?82.html) to which i have connect succesfully over a tcp socket. 
From [the manual](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2ERDkYgeQpndjY5VU03U2VSRjA/edit?usp=sharing) of this controller i read that i have to send a command like that:
**"A5 A5 A5 A5 A5 A5 A5 A5 01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 02 05 00 A2 00 01 00 00 68 F8
5A"**

Now i'm tottaly confused about that command.
How can i send this command through the socket?

**The manual mentions only rs232 and gprs communication the one i have communicates through wifi so i opened a tcp socket*

Answer (score 1):

A very basic approach would be this:

```
int targetPort = 5005;
String targetHost = "targetHost";
byte[] command = new byte[] { (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xa5, ... };
try (Socket socket = new Socket(targetHost, targetPort);
        OutputStream rawOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream()) {
    rawOutputStream.write(command);
    rawOutputStream.flush();
}
```

This merely opens up a socket to your controller, sends the command and that's it. For productive use, you probably would want to keep the socket around, read the answer, maybe wrap the socket's output stream with a `BufferedOutputStream` etc.